# Window 7 commands not running

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Specifically trying `attrib`, but I believe all commands in System32 don't work. I had an issue with a path variable, which I believe is fixed now, since `C:\Windows\System32` is showing at the end of my `%path%` variable. BUT `attrib` still doesn't work:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\tri-eng>echo %path%
C:\oracle\x86;C:\oracle\iqms\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
APP\bin\x 86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD
APP\bin\x86;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Prog
ram Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
Technologies\ATI. ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Dell\Dell Data
Protection\Access\Advanced\Wave\ Gemalto\Access Client\v5\;C:\Program
Files (x86)\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Sof tware
Stack\bin\;C:\Program Files\NTRU Cryptosystems\NTRU TCG Software
Stack\bin " ;C:\Users\tri-eng\Documents\nodejs\;C:\Windows\System32;

C:\Users\tri-eng>attrib
// DOESN'T WORK! 
'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or
external command, operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\tri-eng>C:\Windows\System32\attrib A           
// WORKS!
// ...(output of attrib command)...


C:\Users\tri-eng>
```

Maybe something with the registry?

Comment: Is that a single instance of a double quote `"` in your path?

Comment: If I were to hazard a guess.  Your PATH variable is to long.  Use the shorten versions of those directories to shorten the length.  Start with the basics verify the length of the current variable is within the limits.

Comment: Also...."C:\Windows\System32\" isn't even in your PATH variable?  So of course `attrib` won't be recgonized without a full path to the executable.

Comment: Look carefully: **%SystemRoot%\system32** is defined. Windows does not use the absolute path, but the variable *SystemRoot* for the Windows directory.

Comment: Well, the path that is in the post is not too long. The " would be an issue I imagine though.

Comment: @JasonAller YES, good catch. Thats making the last item `C:\Windows\System32` not work. My answer below was causing the  earlier instance (`%SystemRoot%\system32`) to not be expanded. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `%PATH%` environment variable wasn't automatically expanded, i.e. the `%systemroot%` value wasn't expanded to `C:\Windows\System32`.

This was caused by a bad re-write of my `%PATH%` environment variable during a software install.

To fix it, I replaced the `%PATH%` registry entry as follows:

In Windows 7:

1. Search for `regedit.exe` and run it. GUI opens.
2. Navigate down to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > ControlSet > Control > Session Manager > Environment`
3. Check to see the Type of the PATH variable. If it's REG_SZ, this fix may work.
4. Copy contents of PATH variable to notepad for safekeeping
5. Delete PATH variable
6. Right click > New > Expandable String Variable
7. Set name as PATH
8. Set contents to value copied in step 4
9. REBOOT IS REQUIRED TO TAKE EFFECT